# Text exceeding maximum height and width of the container

Tags: css, reactjs

desktop:

[image]

mobile devices:

[image]

Hello I have a problem my text is passing my maximum height
I would like my container to follow the height and that my text has maximum width of my container my text

code:

```
<div className="App">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div className="text">
      <div class="card-info">
        <div class="card-about">
          <a class="card-tag tag-news">NEWS</a>
          <div class="card-time">6/11/2018</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3 className="textxd">dasssssssssssssssss</h3>
      <p className="textxd">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu dasuhduashu aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu
        dasuhduashu aaaaaaaaaaaaa da aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu dasuhduashu
        aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu dasuhduashu aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu
        dasuhduashu aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu dasuhduashusuhdasudhu
        dasuhduashu aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu dasuhduashu
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.App {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  height: 40vh;
}


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 30vh;
  max-height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background:blue;

}
.textxd {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.text {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 30vh;
  padding: 0.15rem 1.25rem;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  ${({ isHover }) =>
    isHover &&
    `
  color:black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
   `}
}
.card-about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
}
.card-tag {
  width: 60px;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #ffab00;
  color: #fff;
}
.card-info {
  position: relative;
}
```

I do not know how I could solve this I would need to leave my container and responsive text that my container follows the height of the text or that the text has a maximum height

Comment: if you want the height to adjust, just remove the fixed height value.

Comment: remove the max-height for mobile screen. use media queries

Answer (score 1):

If you want the class wrapper with the same height, then use
    overflow: scroll. like this -->

```
.wrapper { ...  overflow : scroll; }
```

OR Else use height : auto;

```
.wrapper { ...  height : auto;   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `height` `auto` on mobile devices like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .wrapper {
  height: auto;
  max-height: auto;    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try This.added max-width to your div .class attribute was also given wrong as className

```css
.App {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
 
}


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background:blue;

}
.textxd {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.text {
 height:auto;
  max-width:100px;
 
  padding: 0.15rem 1.25rem;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  ${({ isHover }) =>
    isHover &&
    `
  color:black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
   `}
}
.card-about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
}
.card-tag {
  width: 60px;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #ffab00;
  color: #fff;
}
.card-info {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">
      <div class="card-info">
        <div class="card-about">
          <a class="card-tag tag-news">NEWS</a>
          <div class="card-time">6/11/2018</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3 className="textxd">dasssssssssssssssss</h3>
      <p className="textxd">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu dasuhduashu aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu
        dasuhduashu aaaaaaaaaaaaa da aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu dasuhduashu
        aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu dasuhduashu aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu
        dasuhduashu aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu dasuhduashusuhdasudhu
        dasuhduashu aaaaaaaaaaaaa dasuhdasudhu dasuhduashu
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```